# Android Error: No virtual method verifyPhoneNumber

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After typing my phone number on the authentication page, I had this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.socialnet, PID: 1376
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method verifyPhoneNumber(Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;Lcom/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks;Lcom/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider$ForceResendingToken;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider' appears in /data/app/com.example.socialnet-1/base.apk)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneNumberVerificationHandler.verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneNumberVerificationHandler.java:31)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment.onNext(CheckPhoneNumberFragment.java:160)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment.onClick(CheckPhoneNumberFragment.java:136)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6377)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Here are the dependencies on the app-level gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
```

I've been looking for a solution for a while but I haven't found any. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please post code where you got error

Comment: @Ashish The code is ok, I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the dependencies, I just can't tell exactly what.